# why image is rotated when i get Fourier transform of image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, fft

I process image using MatLab.

I do the following steps on an image:

1. I make an image read.
2. I take the Fourier of image.
3. I take the real of Fourier transformed image.

While performing above steps I got a double rotated image in result. I don't know its reason why this happened.

Can some one please explain its reason that why in result a double rotated image produced?

The piece of code is here:

```
imfftreal = real(imfft);
im = uint8(ifft2(imfftreal));
imshow(im);
Figure;
```

Comment: please attach the input image and the resulting "rotated image" so we can better understand your problem.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/30770/why-real-part-of-fft-converts-image-into-rotation-original

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the image right you need the imaginary part also. You used only the real part while taking inverse transform.

```
imfftReal = real(imfft);
imfftImag = imag(imfft);
re_imfft=imfftReal +1i*imfftImag;
im = uint8(ifft2(re_imfft));
imshow(im);
```

In case of Magnitude and Phase

```
imfftMagnitude = abs(imfft);
imfftPhase = angle(imfft);
re_imfft=imfftMagnitude.*exp(1i*imfftPhase);
im = uint8(ifft2(re_imfft));
imshow(im);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answer but my question is why image double rotated what is the theory behind this i want to know that please explain...

Answer (score 0):

I experienced same issue exactly and posted it on DSP StackExchange mere two days ago.

[@M529](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/19501/m529) given a very good and simple explanation of it:

> If you have a data set which is purely real, its (inverse) Fourier transform will have Hermitian symmetry: If you find the value z at position (x,y), then you will find the complex conjugate value z∗ at the point-reflected position (−x,−y) about the origin. Note that the origin here would be the center of Fourier-space. This can be reformulated, of course, if the DC component is not in the center of your FFT implementation. And this is what you see in your image: A point-reflected version is overlaying the true image - because you forced one space to be real valued.
>
> This property is actually being used for accelerating magnetic
>   resonance imaging (MRI) in some cases: MRI acquires the data directly
>   in Fourier-space. Since an ideal MR image can be described by real
>   values only (all excited magnetization vectors have phase 0), you only
>   have to acquire half of the data space, which saves you half of the
>   imaging time. Of course, MR images are not completely real valued due
>   to the limiations of reality... but with a few tricks you can still
>   use this technique advantageously.

If you want to see Maths behind it, you can find the detailed answer by [@ThP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/192031/) there: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/30770/why-real-part-of-fft-converts-image-into-rotation-original/30774#30774